# StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found' while calling webapi from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I use webapi when i hosted it on localhost and tried to invoke it it works fine but when i hosted it to a domain server it returns: `"StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'"`

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xyz.website.com/API");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Store").Result;
```

but the result is:

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Date: Sun, 07 Sep 2014 14:19:28 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 1245
  Content-Type: text/html
}}
```

i think there is a problem with the prefix name ('xyz') before website.com

Comment: any chance it's posting to "http://xyz.website.com/API" + "api/Store". Was having "API/api" in there intended?